# Change NavigationView default pane background in cs code

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui

I'm using `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView`. For some reason, I have to change `NavigationView`'s pane background.
So I changed in XAML.

```
<Page.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground" Color="{StaticResource ViuPageBackgroundColor1}" />
</Page.Resources>
```

But now I want to achieve this in cs code, how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground` brush is used for a property called [PaneBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.panebackground?view=winrt-19041) of the Splitview control. The `Splitview` control called **RootSplitView** is one of the components of `Navigationview`.

If you want to change the PaneBackground property in code-behind, you need to search in the `NavigationView`'s template and find the `Splitview` control by name -**RootSplitView**. Then when you get the `Splitview` control, you could change the `PaneBackground` as you want.